# Blank screen while running Remote View on a headless Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, ubuntu-11.04

Ubuntu has constant problems connecting via remote view, I encountered many problems before too, but now it is very persistent.

So today, I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on a headless server. I have limited access to an external monitor at work. I tried to configure everything, but wasn't able to install the SSH server since at work – through proxy – `apt-get` doesn't work. So I enabled remote view hoping I could get it set up at home.

I connect the server to the router, and fire it up, I connect from a laptop also running Ubuntu 11.04.

First, I see the login screen of the target machine. I login successfully and I'm taken to the desktop of the target machine. I enter the password for the remote viewer and restart the target machine after doing some tweaks with temporary files.

After restarting, I can't connect anymore! All I see is a blank black screen. Remote view doesn't show anything, it just sits there empty and black.

I don't have a monitor at home, and no SSH, so what are my options? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. kind of... Removing the password for accessing remotely solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You severed the connection when you restarted the remote machine. from that point, you would have needed to re-initiate the connection again.